# FirestoreAdminClient.exportDocuments has permission from local Firebase Function but not from remote Firebase Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

## Question

How can we give a remote Firebase Function permission to run `FirestoreAdminClient.exportDocuments`?

## What We Have Tried

Locally, we can run the following code. We start the local server and then call the local function that invokes `backupDatabase`. The function successfully initiates a Firestore export operation.

```
firebase login
firebase serve
curl <functionUrl>
```

However, when we deploy the function and then call the remote function that invokes `backupDatabase`, we receive `7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission.`.

This is the code that is working locally but failing remotely.

```
import firebaseAdmin from 'firebase-admin';

const backupDatabase = async (): Promise<string> => {
  const projectId = process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT;
  const adminClient = new firebaseAdmin.firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();
  const [success] = await adminClient.exportDocuments({ // <--- ERROR HERE
    name: adminClient.databasePath(projectId, '(default)'),
    outputUriPrefix: `gs://${projectId}-backups`
  });

  return success.name;
};
```

## Resources

Documentation for `FirestoreAdminClient`: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/v1.FirestoreAdminClient.html

Documentation for `exportDocuments`: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/v1.FirestoreAdminClient.html#exportDocuments

Comment: What roles does the Cloud functions service account has?

Comment: @EnriqueDelValle Thank you for the help. It turned out that we were mistakenly overriding the Firebase Functions default service account in the remote environment by writing a private key filename to the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environmental variable. The private key file was available locally but not remotely. Fixing that resolved the problem.